# XmlHttpRequest with If-Modified since, webserver returns "400 Bad Request"

Tags: javascript, iis-7, xmlhttprequest

Whenever I use the following code, the webserver (running IIS 7) refuses to send me content, but sends a "400 Bad Request" instead.

```
request.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently many people are having this problem, and it can easily be fixed by prefixing the date with a 0.

```
request.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks, I suffered from the same trouble. 
But what is the core reason? Is sending "1 Jan 2000" some RCF violation? Or just IIS7's feature?

Comment: @Shrike indeed II7 is correctly respecting the RFC: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1

Comment: man, I almost went nuts with this bug and then your answer comes along.. thank you so much, I owe you a beer IRL for this